Hibernate log inside stdout
I'm facing an issue with a Spring Boot 3.2.3 application using Hibernate 6.4.4, Logback, and an Oracle database (ojdbc10). I'm trying to disable the logging of Hibernate queries to the standard output.
Currently, Hibernate query logs are appearing in the stdout with the following format:
Hibernate: SELECT A FROM B

It seems like a simple System.out.println call, as there's no timestamp included in the log.
I've tried setting various Spring properties to false or error as suggested in different answers, but it hasn't worked:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=error
logging.level.org.hibernate=error
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=error
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=error
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=error
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW=error
logging.level.org.hibernate.cache=error
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=ERROR
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=ERROR

logback.xml
<configuration  scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" debug="false">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${APP_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%.-30thread][%X{gatewayId}| %X{requestId}] %logger{70} - %msg%n%ex</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="etcd" level="${ETCD_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.http" level="${APACHE_HTTP_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="${KAFKA_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="${SPRING_FWK_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}"/>
    <logger name="n" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="LF-ASYNC"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="{APP_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>

Can someone help here?

please provide the complete logging message (the complete line, which also shows from which class log was made)

Hibernate: select a from b
That's the pattern i was talking about.
There is no timestamp, no class.

could it be just a forgotten System.out.println in your code? (search for Hibernate: text). Otherwise please provide your logging config (e.g. logback-spring.xml)

No System.out in all the source code.

I would suggest that you change spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql to true, and logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL to "trace" or "info".

Are configuring JPA yourself instead of letting Spring Boot handle this? Do you have other properties in there that interfere? Is there a rogue persistence.xml or hibernate.properties in your project? I also wonder of the logging.level actually still works if you provide your own logback.xml.

to check if it is really configurable from the configs you have, I would turn on all the SQL logging for one run, then check if that select appears there twice. If yes, it's not from the logs you configured. If no, it's some extra-thingy. Maybe a second "private" logging lib? Did you also check for occurences of System.err... not just System.out?

@cyberbrain no System.err inside the source code.
No hibernate.properties, persistence.xml i just have the application.properties file.
